# Enhancing the performance of Expectation Maximization

Tags: c++, linux, machine-learning, data-mining, expectation-maximization

I am implementing expectation maximization (EM) in C++ to estimate the parameter of Gaussian mixture model.

The EM is very slow to converge - is there a technique to converge log likelihood in a fast way?

Comment: You should post the code you have now and ask more specific question.

Comment: In fact, it only converges at the limit of your precision. If you had infinite precision, it would never converge. So choose a different threshold.

Comment: yes,thank you, i will check by taking other threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Armadillo C++ library](http://arma.sourceforge.net) has a multi-threaded implementation of Expectation Maximization (EM) for Gaussian Mixure Models (GMM). See the [gmm_diag](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#gmm_diag) class for more information.

Comment: Hello @Mtall pls can u give me a best document and example on gmm_diag what type of input need?